# True Or False validation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a true or false game and need help writing the function to validate if the user is right or wrong. My DOM structure is as follows:

```
<ul class="multiplechoice_answergroup">
  <li class="multiplechoice_answer True">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkme">
    <p>This answer is true</p>
  </li>

  <li class="multiplechoice_answer False">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkme">
    <p>This answer is false</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the jquery that I tried, but I keep getting that the answer is correct:

```
truefalseSubmit = function() {
    if($('.multiplechoice_answergroup').children('li').hasClass('False') && $('.multiplechoice_answergroup').children('li').find('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)')){
      correctAnswer();
    } else if($('.multiplechoice_answergroup').children('li').hasClass('True') && $('.multiplechoice_answergroup').children('li').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')){
        correctAnswer();
    } else {
      incorrectAnswer();
    }

  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by “if the user is right or wrong”? And why are you using checkboxes apparently for a yes/no choice, instead of radio buttons?

Comment: This is my question as well.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/pagazuja/1/edit  is another alternative and doesn't uses the li elements themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should rather go like this:

```
truefalseSubmit = function() {
  var $trueCheckbox = $('.multiplechoice_answergroup li.True input[type="checkbox"]');
  var $falseCheckbox = $('.multiplechoice_answergroup li.False input[type="checkbox"]');
  if ($trueCheckbox.is(':checked') && $falseCheckbox.is(':not(:checked)')) {
    correctAnswer();
  } else {
    incorrectAnswer();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then doing

```
$('.multiplechoice_answergroup').children('li')
   .find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

you should do

```
$('.multiplechoice_answergroup').children('li')
   .find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")
```

Reason:

`find()` returns a jQuery object which validates to true in JavaScript. So the first or the second if expression will always be true, the part following `&&` is always true.

Here of course too:

```
$('.multiplechoice_answergroup').children('li').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":not(:checked)")
```

Comment: You could also continue doing the find and check the length of the collection.  `$('.multiplechoice_answergroup li input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0` will return true if any exist that are checked, false otherwise.

Comment: @ps2goat You could, but personally I think `is` is more comfortable.

Comment: I keep getting that its a correct answer no matter what I do

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
truefalseSubmit = function() {
    $('.multiplechoice_answer input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        /**
         * Check if the parent div where checkbox is, has the class "true"
         */

            if($(this).parent().hasClass('true'))
                return correctAnswer();

        /**
         * Answer is incorrect
         */

            return incorrectAnswer();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not like that?

html:

```
<ul>
  <li class="answer-button true">
    <p>This answer is true</p>
  </li>

  <li class="answer-button false">
    <p>This answer is false</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
var answerHandler = function (answer) {
    // do something
};
$('.answer-button').click(function () {
    answerHandler($(this).hasClass('true'));
});
```